# mssql query, set non xml data size

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I try to convert a few table(MSSQL) into an xml file.
the result has been truncated at 2.7 MB (just 2KB before the end).

If I increase the "non xml data" size and "xml data" size in the vs express(SQL>execution settings>query options...>resutls>grid> "non xml data" and "xml data") then I get the exact result

So the query is working fine.

Only problem, I need this in a program(c#) not in the query window.

I use executexmlreader.

Someone has any ideal, what can be wrong?

```
        SqlConnection testConnection = new SqlConnection();
        testConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
        testConnection.Open();

        TestCommand = new SqlCommand("exec prAdvListToXML", testConnection);

        XmlReader TestXmlReader = TestCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
        XmlWriter TestFileWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\temp\output.xml");
        TestFileWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'");

        TestFileWriter.WriteNode(TestXmlReader, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem has nothing to do with XML at all (certainly, the behavior of Management Studio is a red herring). You do not close your writer anywhere, nor do you make sure all data has been processed. Try rewriting your code so resources are properly disposed of:

```
using (var testConnection = new SqlConnection()) {
    testConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
    testConnection.Open();
    using (var testCommand = new SqlCommand("exec prAdvListToXML", testConnection))
    using (XmlReader testXmlReader = testCommand.ExecuteXmlReader())
    using (XmlWriter testFileWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\temp\output.xml")) {
        testFileWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'");
        testFileWriter.WriteNode(testXmlReader, true);
    }
}
```